# How to pass colours through with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, video-conversion, color-depth

I've noticed that the videos I've been encoding over the last few months are slightly more yellow compared to their original sources. This is very annoying because I would have expected the default behaviour to pass through colour information. Is this not the case?

I'm transcoding from `libvpx` to `libx264`. Here is the output from the last command I ran in which this problem occurred:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mkv" -preset ultrafast -to 6:53 -c:v libx264 -crf 15 -c:a copy -vf "crop=320:160:0:40,scale=-2:1080" "test.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-100422-gff6f8c272e-g1eb751955e+1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --pkg-config=pkgconf --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --disable-autodetect --enable
-amf --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-
lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --en
able-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e
nable-libdav1d --enable-libaom --disable-debug --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-openssl --extra-libs=-liconv
--enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 93.100 /  7. 93.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'source.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.65.100
  Duration: 00:07:49.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 240 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 320x240, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 18 fps, 18 tbr, 1k t
bn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:07:49.221000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/11/2019.
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      DURATION        : 00:07:49.275000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] 264 - core 161 r3027 4121277 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 -
 http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=
1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip
=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_
compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=18 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=c
rf mbtree=0 crf=15.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 2160x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2
:1], q=2-31, 18 fps, 18432 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:07:49.221000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.115.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/11/2019.
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      DURATION        : 00:07:49.275000000
frame= 7434 fps= 47 q=-1.0 Lsize=  748614kB time=00:06:52.99 bitrate=14849.4kbits/s speed=2.62x
video:741826kB audio:6454kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.044636%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] frame I:30    Avg QP:10.10  size:284105
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] frame P:7404  Avg QP:12.51  size:101446
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] mb P  I16..4: 14.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 71.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    sk
ip:14.1%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 45.1% 37.2% 14.8% inter: 53.1% 32.5% 0.9%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] i16 v,h,dc,p: 45% 20% 10% 25%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 17% 21% 15%
[libx264 @ 000002575cffe040] kb/s:14714.37
```

How do I pass through the colour information of my source so that the colour of the output is always the same as that of my source?

Comment: Do all players/browsers show a color difference? Or just certain ones? Also, upscaling from 320x160 to 2160x1080? Why?

Comment: @llogan Interestingly, the problem seems to only occur in MPC-HC (my main player) - VLC seems to match the source. I take it from your comment that FFmpeg's default behaviour is already to pass colour information through?

Comment: Not really. See [Your browser and my browser see different colors](https://mux.com/blog/your-browser-and-my-browser-see-different-colors/)

Comment: @llogan Very interesting article that basically seems to confirm that FFmpeg doesn't pass through colour information and agree with me that it should: "Even though the colorspace filter could read the source colorspace, and we specifically specified a new destination colorspace, ffmpeg did not write a correct vui to the resulting file... Ffmpeg is by far the most commonly used tool for video conversion. And here it is dropping color information. Second, while ffmpeg is an amazing piece of software, its ubiquity, semi-ease of use and unfortunate defaults are problematic at best."

Comment: @llogan I take it from this that currently the best solution for colour consistency (as much as possible) is to get the colorspace of my source, convert to that AND then set the colorspace metadata?

Comment: @llogan With regards to the upscaling, it's so I can merge it with a YouTube outro of the same resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Oct 2020](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/7369595c55), ffmpeg relays colorimetry properties detected in the source onto the destination, so make sure your ffmpeg is more current than that. 4.4 is the oldest release that has the change.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't get over the fact that FFmpeg's default behaviour is to discard the source's colour information, and silently too at that, and can only hope this is a problem that will be solved soon.

In the meantime, it seems this information must be passed through explicitly by specifying the color metadata.

For my own case, adding:

```
-color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m -colorspace smpte170m
```

to my command seems to be enough to preserve the colorspaces of my own sources.

Credit goes to llogan for the [link](https://mux.com/blog/your-browser-and-my-browser-see-different-colors/) which these commands come from.

Comment: *FFmpeg's default behaviour is to discard the source's colour information* --> this was fixed in Oct 2020. But your input is shown as `yuv420p(tv)`, meaning color info isn't detected in the source.

Comment: @Gyan Which commit is that?

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/7369595c55

Comment: @Gyan That's good to know, feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept. Is `yuv420p(tv)` the FFmpeg fallback for when colour can't be dectected, or is there another reason my input is showing as that?

Comment: *Is yuv420p(tv) the FFmpeg fallback for when colour can't be dectected* --> no, it is showing the information that is available. `yuv420p` is the pixel format. `tv` is the color range.